# iPhone New Facebbok SDK . post to wall not coming

Tags: facebook, sdk, new-operator

My Code is successfully running in Simulator(evn after implementing New Facebook SDK).

But when i checked in device, Code is running,

but Post To Wall not coming.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and solved it,
If use are using method:
 [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];" 
in FbGraph.m file.

then Before calling this method declare the following variables as nil
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *err =nil;